# Sublime Text 2: Autoload new files in the list

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext2

**I'm on ubuntu, using v 2.0.1 Build 2217**

Previously I was using sublime text 2 on mac, and when I was creating a new file by command line `$ touch test.php` or simply from sublime text by right-clicking on a folder then click new File, I was able to see my new file into my files tree on the left side.

But now I'm using ST2 on Ubuntu and every time I create or generate (Zend) a file, it doesn't appear in my files tree, for now I close and reopen ST2 every time I create a new file.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed temporarily (until you stop your login session) by running the following. It will set the amount of file watches Linux will allow:

```
 sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=32768
```

Then restart Sublime Text.

If Sublime's File Tree now works you are able to persist this file watch configuration with:

```
echo 32768 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

Same issue as Atom and this fix works on Ubuntu 15.10 with Sublime Text 3

- https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/docs/build-instructions/linux.md#typeerror-unable-to-watch-path
- https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/2082